# Python type casting in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to make a list in Python 3.4.3 containing numbers between -10 to 10 with a step of .1 difference, so that my list becomes: `a =[-10.0,-9.9,-9.8,-9.7............. 9.9,10]`
 I also want to draw a graph using `matplotlob.pyplot` ,
Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = []
b = []
for i in range(-10,10,.1):
    a.append(i)
npa = np.array(a)
npb= np.array(b)
npb = 1 / (npa**2)
plt.plot(npa, npb)
plt.show()
```

But I'm getting error saying:
    `for i in range(-10,10,.1):
    TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`
Any solution,please?

and for these lines:

```
a = []
b = []
for i in range(-10,10,.1):
    a.append(i)
```

is there any shorter code?

Comment: In case it isn't obvious from the duplicate, `npa = np.arange(-10, 10, .1)`.  And drop the `npb=np.array(b)` line.  `npb` does not need to be 'initialized'.

Comment: @hpaulj, is there is short code by which i can `a = [ ] ` and 

`for i in range(-10,10,1):
    a.append(i) `
joining together? like `a = for i range(-10, 10, 1)`  ,is it possible?

Comment: `a=[i for i in range(...)]`; or just `a=list(range(...))`.  The list is needed in Py3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
for i in range(-100,100,1):
    a.append(i/10)
```

The problem is that you cannot use a float index in a for loop

You could do too:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
```

Comment: Actually, I think the real problem was the decimal step. Even without a for loop, I got the same error just with `range(-10, 10, 0.1)`.

Comment: @nacho , Thanks a lot ,it worked !!!